# Swift: Does Array conforms to Sequence Protocol?

Tags: arrays, swift, sequence

I found out that `Array` has `makeIterator()` method. 
As I know, `makeIterator()` is required by the `Sequence` protocol. 
But I couldn't find the fact that `Array` conforms to `Sequence`.

Does `Array` conforms to `Sequence` protocol?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find what protocols built-in types conform to in their documentation. There is a `Relationships` section at the bottom of their documentation pages.

If you check the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) of `Array`, you can see that it conform to `MutableCollection`, which inherits from `Collection`, which inherits from `Sequence`. So yes, `Array` does conform to `Sequence` via its `MutableCollection` conformance.